# Is is possible for mods or admins to edit someone else's comment?

Tags: support, comments, edits

Made a comment, edited said comment, came back and I swear my comment was subtly different than what I had written. It showed that the comment had been edited 3 times -- I might have done it twice. I've since deleted said comment, but I'm wondering who, if anyone, has the ability to edit my comments.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes. ♦ moderators and devs can edit anyone's comments. Typically, this is only exercised just to do minor spelling fixes, remove dangerous content, or at request as per some flags.

We are also not limited as to how long of a window we can edit anyone's comments, but editing any comment other than our own is in fact tracked.

Comment: Note that only the "diamond"( the elected or appointed mods) can do this, 10K users can **not**

Comment: @Jacob I don't really call 10k users moderators, so that's technically the intent, but I'll just clarify that. ♪

Comment: True, but some people think of 10K users as mods, so I wanted to clarify that.

Comment: @Jacob You've got a lotta posts ahead of you to clear that up, then. ♪

Comment: 10k users have access to mod tools, therein lies where people are too lazy to remember the difference that a moderator has a diamond and 10k do not @jac

Comment: @Grace Note - anyway I can see who has edited my comment if someone other than I did it?

Comment: @tvan Only moderators and above get access to that info, so there's no way you can see that unless you can get elected or ask a moderator to find out for you.

Comment: @Grace Note - so someone can change what I've said and I get no notification of it and can't find out who it was.  That seems...wrong.

Comment: @tvan We're elected under the trust that we *not* do that. Like I intentionally qualified in my answer, this is generally done only for spelling fixes, dangerous content removal, and at the author's request; changing the intent of the comment is pretty standard abuse. If we have to make significant changes that the author should know about, most of us will actually notify the author in the process, should we edit rather than entirely delete the comment (which we also can do, recall).

Comment: @Grace Note - I'm more of a trust and verify kind of guy.  Why not make the changes transparent?  That is, instead of the hover over saying "this comment was edited" say "this comment was edited by the owner" or "this comment was edited by a moderator".

Comment: @tvan Because comments are lightweight, oft unimportant, and usually the nature of the edit of a comment is insignificant. We likewise do not indicate when a comment was edited, or what was changed about it. If it still concerns you, I invite you to make a proper feature request out of it.